# Удалить все из строки кроме ключевого слова

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Как можно удалить все из строки кроме одного клчевого слова?

```
import re
s = 'запиши пожалуйста текст'
reg = re.compile('[^запиши]')
print(reg.sub('', s))
```

вот код который я пробовал, но тогда он оставляет в строке запишиаа, можно как-то оставить только запиши, и все?

Comment: Какова ваша задача? Что вы делаете? Удаление любого символа, кроме последовательности символов/шаблона не самая удачная идея, так как нет такого кунструкта в регулярных выражениях. Этого можно достичь несколькими способами с помощью `re.findall`, `re.split` и `re.sub`, непонятно, что нужно именно вам.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А если слово несколько раз в строке встретиться, тогда что должно вывести? А так то такая задача решается без регулярок:

```
import re
s = 'запиши пожалуйста текст'
word = 'запиши'
print(word if word in s else '')
# запиши
```

Ну или если уж хочется с регулярками:

```
import re
s = 'запиши пожалуйста текст'
reg = re.compile('запиши')
print(reg.findall(s))
# ['запиши']
```

Т.е. не "заменять всё, кроме такого-то слова", а наоборот: "найти и показать такое-то слово".

В любом случае вы не можете ничего убрать из строки, вы можете только создать новую строку на основе старой (потому что строки иммутабельны). Мыслить надо в этом направлении: что надо взять в новую строку из старой строки и как это проще сделать.

Comment: вся суть в том что это часть огромного кода, и мне нужно только проверить есть ли в слове это слово, спасибо вам большое за помощь, это именно то что я искал)

Comment: @DisanD_08 Ну, если проверка, что есть слово в строке, то да, это делается через `if word in string:`

Comment: там все сложно, мне нужно проверить если слово в строке, если есть слово убрать, если нет пускать строку дальше по проверкам